# Flow Decision Element Limitation

Tags: flow, visual-workflow, visual-flows

I have flow in which through LookUp I added 20 decision elements. The flow works fine until it reaches 18 decision points then breaks, there is no error message shows up. Hence want to know hard limit on the number of Decision elements that can be used in a flow.

Comment: Are using DML statements in decision flow.@sfdc rowdy

Comment: In decision element I am checking the condition and then using the Assignment element, that means DML operation is performed.